# How do I force lines to be a certain length?

Tags: regex, text, replace, sed

I have a text file that contains a very large list of 5-digit numbers. Some lines contain more than one 5-digit number without a newline separating them

```
12345
23456
34567
4567856789
67890
...
837460174975917
...
```

I'm trying to find a regular expression that I can use with sed that will add newlines in-between the numbers.

The desired output would be:

```
12345
23456
34567
45678
56789
67890
...
83746
01749
75917
...
```

I've played around with it a bit, but the best I can figure out is something like ^([0-9]{5}) replaced with $1/r/n. However, this adds a newline after every digit, and I'd need to remove all the blank lines afterwards which is not optimal because of the size of this file.

Comment: So, sed or Notepad++? In NPP, you could try `^([0-9]{5})\B` and replace with `$1\r\n$2`

Comment: I'll be using sed becuase the file is too large for notepad++. Solution can be either or, because I'm just looking for a regular expression that does what I want.

Comment: sed does not support Boost regex flavor as NPP. Try `sed -E "s/^([0-9]{5})(.)/\1\r\n\2/g"`

Answer (score 2):

Light weight solution using `fold` :

Sample input:

```
cat filename
12345
23456
34567
4567856789
```

Solution using fold:

```
cat filename|fold -w5
12345
23456
34567
45678
56789
```

Update(As suggested by Kenavoz):  To avoid unnecessary use of `cat` and `pipe`

```
fold -w5 filename
```

Comment: Or `fold -w5 filename` to avoid pipe.

Answer (score 1):

Using `grep -o` you can do this:

```
grep -Eo '.{5}' file

12345
23456
34567
45678
56789
67890
83746
01749
75917
```